# Are Linux commands really C object files?

Tags: c, linux, unix, object-files

I was reading "The C Programming Language" by Kernighan & Ritchie and came across some programs which mimic some Unix commands (also implemented in Linux) such as the `cat` command. The program took command line arguments just like the original `cat` command.
I am just curious to know whether they are the same thing or not.
Correct me if I'm wrong, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Per your headline, the answer is yes. But voting to close, as this is off-topic for Stackoverflow. Good luck.

Comment: You mean Brian W. Kernighan and Dennis M. Ritchie? The folks who invented C to invent Unix? And you're wondering that their `cat` command resembles the `cat` used today?

Comment: Many of these commands are, on some Linux-distributions, part of GNU's coreutils package. You can find the source code for many of these tools [here](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src).

Comment: K&R's cat probably took fewer options than today's cat.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick And how!  The original `cat` had *zero* options, and when it got its first one, there were cries of alarm from the die-hard Unix old guard, and one of them wrote a widely-circulated essay, *cat -v Considered Harmful*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a command-line environment (such as, of course, Unix/Linux), a principle unit of abstraction is the *command*.  A command has a well-defined interface: the command-line arguments it expects, the input it reads (if any), and the output it generates.  You can reimplement a command any time you like, either using a different internal algorithm, or a different language, or just because you want to write your own version.  Yes, `cat` was originally written in C, but we could rewrite it in C++, or Perl, or Python, or sh, or other languages.  As long as our reimplementation meets the same interface requirements, we can accurately say that it "is" `cat`.